# What is the difference between clojure's APersistentMap implementations

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to figure out what the difference is between a PersistentHashMap, PersistentArrayMap, PersistentTreeMap, and PersistentStructMap.

Also if I use `{:a 1}` it gives me a PersistentArrayMap but can this change to any of the other ones if I give it objects or things other than keys?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The four implementations you list fall into three groups:

1. *"literal"*: `PersistentArrayMap` and `PersistentHashMap`: basic map types used when dealing with map literals (though constructor functions are also available with different behaviour around handling duplicate keys -- in Clojure 1.5.x literals throw exceptions when they discover duplicate keys, constructor functions work like left-to-right repeated `conj`ing; this behaviour has been evolving from version to version). Array maps get promoted to hash maps when growing beyond a certain number of entries (9 IIRC). Array maps exist because they are faster for small maps; they also differ from hash maps in that they keep entries in insertion order prior to promotion to hash map (you can use `clojure.core/array-map` to get arbitrarily large array maps, which may be useful if you really know you'd benefit from insertion-order traversals and the map won't be too large, perhaps just a bit over the usual threshold; NB. a subsequent `assoc` to such an oversized array map will return a hash map). Array maps use arrays with keys and values interleaved; the PHM uses a persistent version of Phil Bagwell's hash array mapped trie with separate chaining for hash collisions and separate node types for mostly-empty and at-least-half-full nodes and is easily the most complex data structure in Clojure.
2. *sorted*: `PersistentTreeMap` instances are created by special request only (a call to `sorted-map` or `sorted-map-by`). They are implemented as red-black trees and maintain entries in a particular order, as specified by the default `compare` comparator if created with `sorted-map` or a user-supplied comparator if created with `sorted-map-by`.
3. *special-purpose, probably deprecated*: `PersistentStructMap` is not used very often and mostly viewed as deprecated in favour of records, although I actually can't remember right now if there ever was an official deprecation notice. The original purpose was to provide maps with particularly fast access to certain often-used keys. This can now be accomplished with records when using keywords for field access (with the keyword in the operator position: `(:foo instance-of-some-record-with-field-foo)`), though it's important to note that records are not `=` to regular maps with the same entries.

All these four built-in map types fall into the same "equality partition", that is, any two maps of one of the four classes mentioned above will be equal if (and only if) they contain the same keys (as determined by Clojure's `=`) with the same corresponding values. Records, as mentioned in 3. above, are map-like, but each record type forms its own equality partition.

Answer (score 5):

They are different implementation of a Persistent Map (they all extend `APersistentMap`). So a  `PersistentArrayMap` uses an array as the underlying data structure to implement persistent map and similarly other implementations uses different underlying data stucture.

The reason for different implementation is they provide different benefits in different situations (as the efficiency of the implementation depends on the underlying data structure).

From a developer perspective, it is abstracted away and hence you should not be directly using 
them and instead work with the `APersistentMap` abstract class or `IPersistentMap` interface (in case some type checking etc is required for some specific case).

Depending on the number of elements in the map the various implementations are used.

```
(type (into {} (map #(-> [% %]) (range 5))))
=> PersistentArrayMap
(type (into {} (map #(-> [% %]) (range 10))))
=> PersistentHashMap
```