# Does Clojure have a set that remembers insertion order?

Tags: clojure

Like Java's [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).  So instead of this:

```
(-> #{} (conj 1 2 3 4 5) vec)
=> [1 4 3 2 5]
```

You get:

```
 (-> ??? (conj 1 2 3 4 5) vec)
=> [1 2 3 4 5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in the core library, but there's [this one](https://github.com/amalloy/ordered/blob/develop/src/flatland/ordered/set.clj).

```
(use 'flatland.ordered.set)

(ordered-set 4 3 1 8 2)
=> #ordered/set (4 3 1 8 2)

(conj (ordered-set 9 10) 1 2 3)
=> #ordered/set (9 10 1 2 3)

(into (ordered-set) [7 6 1 5 6])
=> #ordered/set (7 6 1 5)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why they have `ordered-map`? I was just testing Clojure's native map and it seems to behave that way already. Maybe I'm just getting lucky.

Comment: Core has `sorted-map` but no `ordered-map`. I believe the native map preserves insertion order _incidentally_ when you have very few (ten or less?) keys, because the maps are backed by different data structures depending on how many keys they have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16516760